# java jpa : list and sublist

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I have a java object that I have persisted using JPA. This object has a member 'friendsList' that is a list of strings. I have used the @CollectionOfElements hibernate annotation on this object. The result of this is that I have two tables, one that persists my object, and another that persists the lists of each of these objects.

How can I retrieve (using jpa) all objects whose lists contain 'hello' or 'world' ?

Comment: I haven't checked that but it should be something like this: `select p from Parent p join p.friendsList f where f in ('hello', 'world')`

Answer (score 0):

Following is working fine : it will also create a `Parent_names` table for maintaining relationships. **Don't annotate with @OneToMany**

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = String.class)
    private List<String> names;
```

Or I think you can try a workaround :
Wrap string inside a class.

```
class FriendsName{
private String name;
//getter setter
}
```

Then,

```
class Parent{
@OneToMany
List<FriendsName> friendsName;
}
```

And you can do JPQL like:

```
select p from Parent p where p.friendsName.name in ('hello','world')
```

Comment: Creating an entity (`FriendsName`) just for a simple string is not a good idea

Comment: @AdamDyga : Yeah , but then , even @ ElementCollection should work.